# How to find the centroid of an object in the point cloud?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

Can anyone tell me how to find the centroid of an object in point cloud?.
I haven't tried any code yet because I have no slight idea as to how to go about it.

Comment: Did you try Google? This was [literally the first result](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_centroid_point.html).

Comment: The question's unclear, why not just average all the points? If not, do you mean the convex hull of the points?

Comment: Use this:

`Eigen::Vector4f centroid;`

 `pcl::compute3DCentroid (*cloud, centroid);` 

 `cout << "centroid:" << centroid[0] << " " <<  centroid[1] << " " <<   centroid[2] << " " <<   centroid[3] << " \n";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the point locations, you should be able to just average the x and y positions.

```
int x = 0; y = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < num_pts; i++ )
{
    x += pt[i].x;
    y += pt[i].y;
}
centroid.x = x / num_pts;
centroid.y = y / num_pts;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the native PCL approach: `pcl::computeCentroid(pointCloud, outCentroid);`